# Driver for RTL-8139 required for Enter E-100E Ethernet Card - Can't compile source file

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, driver

I purchased an **Enter E-100E Ethernet Card** (http://www.entermultimedia.com/pci_ethernet_10_100_lancard.html) today..

I found that ubuntu can't detect the device. So, I checked out the device driver documentation, which said :

> This document contains instructions on installing Linux driver and adjusting speed for the series of RTL8139(A/B/C/8130) Network Adapter Installing Driver:
>
> (1.) Kernel Had Supported Driver: Check the directory " /lib/modules/¡K./net " if you could find "rtl8139.o" Your kernel had supported RTL8139 series. You could easy use "linuxconf" to setup your card. If you don't like linuxconf, you also could use "modprobe rtl8139" and "ifconfig up eth0" to load module. If your driver load properly, your "/etc/conf.modules" should include line of "alias eth0 rtl8139".
>
> (2.) Kernel Don't Support Driver: If your kernel doesn't support RTL8139 series, you should compiler driver by yourself. Please contact "www.scyld.com/network/rtl8139.html" to get source code. The compiler command is located on the end of source code. Maybe like "gcc -DMODULE -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -O6 -c rtl8139.c". If you couldn't compiler success, maybe you should refer to error message and copy library or head file to Linux.

Now, (1) didn't work for me, as I did not find the said directory (after replacing the ¡K with linux-headers-3.0.8-19).

So, I tried to do (2)..

But, the website is down.. So, I got the source file, **rtl8139.c** from some site online.. However, when I tried to compile it with the included command, the compiler showed an error that the /usr/src/linux (or library, as the case may be) directory didn't exist..

However, I noticed from this site that the Realtek RTL8139 driver is quite famous.. So, I was wondering, am i missing something? Plese Help.. I'm at an dead end..

I'm new to linux and Ubuntu.. So, can someone please tell me what to do... Thanks for taking the time to read this..

Comment: The Source file : ftp://ftp.dlink.com/NIC/dfe530tx+/Driver/Linux/RTL8139.C

Comment: @alk : I've no idea. That's what is in the official documentation of the driver. Also, it gave no error while compiling that was related to that particular command line parameter. :O

Answer (score 1):

Recent Linux kernels support Real-Tek RTL8139 based cards using the `8139too` module.

The `8139too` module is base on the code by Donald Becker you linked.

Do

```
modprobe 8139too
```

or

```
insmod /<path to module>/8139too.ko
```

and then use `ifconfig` as per your posting.

Comment: I tried to do it.. The command returns is successful, although there is **NO OUTPUT**.

But, `ifconfig up eth0` returned "eth0 : internal resolver error"

Comment: Refering "*NO OUTPUT*": Under UNIX "no news" is "good news". You could test whether the module had been loaded using the command `lsmod`.

Comment: On how to configure network interfaces on Ubuntu you might like to study this documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Comment: The computer doesn't seem to recognise eth0.. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output when you just issue `ipconfig` without any parameters on the command line (with the `8139too` module loaded)?

Comment: Its `ifconfig eth0 up`. You mixed the order of options.

Comment: `ifconfig` in all cases shows only l0 (or lo). even if I just did `ifconfig eth0 up`.The computer doesn't seem to recognise eth0.. Any ideas?

Also, `lspci` returns the name of the pci ethernet card, so we know that this not a hardware problem.. 

The `lsmod` shows that 8139too is there, and used by 0.
Curiously, there is also one called 8139cp.. I believe I did see something earlier on this site, about blacklisting it, but I understood nothing.. Would you kindly look into it, sir??

Comment: What exactly is written in the chip on the networkcard, What is the exact output of `lspci`?

Comment: `ifconfig eth0 up` --> eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device.

Comment: `lspci` --> 06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)

Comment: Now the question is what is written on the chip on the card: 8139 or 8139C or 8139C+? Or even something else?

Comment: Remove the `8139too` by doing `rmmod 8139too` and retry `ifconfig eth0 up`.

Comment: However, either the one or the other driver shall allow a successful `ifconfig eth0 up`.

Comment: Tried doing `ifconfig eth0 up` with both AND either drivers. In all cases I get the error  `eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device`

Comment: @Somu Perhaps the device is not being recognized in the probe() function.  You might have to create a printk() message to learn what device ID it finds and add an entry to the pci_tbl[] table so that it has a match.

Comment: Does the `lspci -v` message you quoted still appear when you pulled out the card out of its slot? If "yes" the messsage belongs to another network adapter.

Comment: @alk : How do I do the printk message thing? And if I pull out the network adapter, `lspci` does not show the ethernet port, so it's recognising the correct card in lspci.